# The importance of bees "highlight" or "highlights"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> The importance of bees (highlight/highlights) the devastating loss that would occur if bee diseases continue to proliferate.

In this sentence, I believe that 'the importance of bees' is its own subject, and by the principle of subject-verb agreement, the correct answer would be 'highlights' as 'the importance of bees' is singular. However, reading the sentence with 'highlights' sounds very weird to me, and 'highlight' sounds much more smooth, which makes me doubt my answer. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Cascabel I am not sure about my answer.

Comment: I don´t know who keeps voting to migrate un-researched questions, but please read ["Please dont migrate"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7191/please-dont-migrate) before a pattern develops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop out the unnecessary parts (grammatically speaking), it becomes clearer.  The phrase ***of bees*** clarifies what *importance* you're talking about, but it isn't strictly necessary.  You could have mentioned that you're talking about the importance of bees in a previous sentence, for example.
So take that out.  Then you get:

> The importance (highlight/highlights) the devastating loss ...

Clearly, at this point, the correct verb is ***highlights***:

> The importance *highlights* the devastating loss ...

And then you can add back in the bits you took out:

> The importance of bees *highlights* the devastating loss ...

The thing doing the highlighting is the *importance* of the bees, not the bees themselves.

Here is some more info on [subject-verb agreement](http://www.aje.com/en/arc/editing-tip-subject-verb-agreement-across-prepositional-phrases/) when a prepositional phrase gets in the way and [here is a worksheet](https://www.bcsoh.org/cms/lib3/OH01001261/Centricity/Domain/720/prepostional%20phrases%20agreement.pdf) with more info and some practice sentences.